# How to have the same shortcode multiple times on a page with different attribute values

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

So I basically need to have the same shortcode multiple times on the same page with different attribute values.

So on my page, I have the following shortcode:

```
[sponsors type="Platinum"]
[sponsors type="Premium"]
[sponsors type="Plus"]
```

Then I have multiple if statements which all state the following:

```
if ( $atts['type'] == 'Platinum' ) {
?>
<h2><?php echo 'working'?></h2>
<?php
} else {}

if ( $atts['type'] == 'Premium' ) {
?>
<h2><?php echo 'working'?></h2>
<?php
} else {}

if ( $atts['type'] == 'Plus' ) {
?>
<h2><?php echo 'working'?></h2>
<?php
} else {}
```

But I noticed when I do this the values just combine and are not specific to each shortcode as when I dumped $atts['type'] I got this string 'Platinum Premium Plus'.

So not sure how else I can do this?

Comment: I think you need something about this. Have you seen
<https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/297003/how-to-use-the-same-shortcode-with-different-attribute-values-on-same-page>?

Answer (score 0):

> How to have the same shortcode multiple times on a page with different attribute values

Exactly how you've done it:

```
[sponsors type="Platinum"]
[sponsors type="Premium"]
[sponsors type="Plus"]
```

The thing is that shortcodes don't `echo` stuff, they have to `return` a string with your code.

Like so:

```
add_shortcode('sponsors', function($atts,$content){
    if ( $atts['type'] == 'Platinium' ) {
        $result = "<h2>Platinum working</h2>";
    }
    else if ( $atts['type'] == 'Premium' ) {
        $result = "<h2>Premium working</h2>";
    }
    else if ( $atts['type'] == 'Plus' ) {
        $result = "<h2>Plus working</h2>";
    }
    return $result;
});
```